# Left Outer Join not working properly

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I am trying to return the top three users with the most uploads. I then have a count to count the number of uploads for each of the 3 top users. Right now it only return one user and the count counts all of the uploads, even if an upload does not belong to that user.

Here's my table setup:

Upload: (id, userID, name, location, type)

User: (id, fname, lname, username, avatar, country, pw)

```
SELECT u.id, u.userID, COUNT(us.id) as top_nums, us.username, us.avatar, us.country 
FROM upload u LEFT OUTER JOIN user us ON us.id=u.userID 
ORDER BY top_nums DESC LIMIT 3
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Explain with sample data

Comment: What specifically is not working properly?

Comment: If you would have read further down you would have seen the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query resolve your problem:

```
SELECT us.id, us.username, us.avatar, us.country, COUNT(u.id) top_nums 
FROM `user` us 
LEFT JOIN upload u ON us.id = u.userId 
GROUP BY u.userID 
ORDER BY top_nums DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed GROUP BY from u.id to u.userID and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you lack `GROUP BY` clause in your query,

```
SELECT  u.id, u.userID, COUNT(us.id) as top_nums, us.username, us.avatar, us.country 
FROM    upload u 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  user us 
            ON us.id=u.userID 
GROUP BY u.id, u.userID, us.username, us.avatar, us.country 
ORDER BY top_nums DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

but bare  in mind that this query will not take care of the ties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
select      u.id, u.fname, u.lname, count(*)
from        user u
left outer join upload up on u.id = up.userid
group by    u.id, u.fname, u.lname
order by    count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select us.username, us.avatar, us.country ,
(select count(*) from upload u where u.id=us.id) as no_of_uploads 
from users us order by 4 desc limit 3;
```